# Error while localizing communityEventsData in script-loader.php

Tags: multisite, core, core-modifications

I'm getting an error in my logs:

```
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in /usr/share/nginx/wp/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php on line 492
```

So I got the stack trace:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /usr/share/nginx/wp/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php
            [line] => 221
            [function] => localize
            [class] => WP_Scripts
            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => dashboard
                    [1] => communityEventsData
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [nonce] => 0c29524bac
                            [cache] => 
                            [time_format] => g:i a
                        )

                )

        )
```

I think that because the key [cache] is empty, this is generating the warning in class.wp-scripts.php
Isn't that all WP core?  Their check to skip is `if ( ! is_scalar( $value ) )` and before the last update I had changed that to `if ( ! is_scalar( $value ) || empty( $value) )` but of course that was overwritten last update.  I'm wondering if I'm missing something or if it's a minor oversight in core.

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to modify core code? That's never a good idea.

Comment: Well I'm saying unmodified core code is throwing an error, to be precise.